# OData API Versioning in .NET 6

Tags: c#, odata, versioning, .net-6.0

I would like to add OData Versioning to a .NET 6 project.
The packages which are included in the project are:

- [Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData - 8.0.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/)
- [Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Versioning - 5.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Versioning/)

Apparently 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Versioning' **v5.0.0** is **not compatible** with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData' **v8.0.4**.

Combination of both packages results in an error:

> CS7069    Reference to type 'ODataModelBuilder' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData', but it could not be found

Does a new package exists or is it baked in to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData package?

Sam XU provided a solution; creating an extension: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/api-versioning-extension-with-asp-net-core-odata-8/ Is this still the way to go, or is there an alternative while using OData >= 8.0.4?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @soccer7 I ended up using the provided solution of Sam XU and modified/ extended to the needs of my project. In the meantime, developers are working on a .NET 6 compatible version of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Versioning package, please have a look at [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/dev/css/preview3-fixes/src)